# rsync not setting the correct UID and GID on destination files

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync

I am testing whether I use the correct options on `rsync` because I want to copy a large amount of files from my old server to the new server keeping exact permissions.

On the old server, the file exists like this:

```
$ ll -n
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 1002 1000 0 Jan  9 22:56 testfile
```

Then I use `rsync` to copy the file like this:

```
$ rsync -e ssh -avP . 10.10.10.254:/home/someuser/test
Enter passphrase for key 'newserver.key':
sending incremental file list
./
testfile
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/2)

sent 125 bytes  received 34 bytes  28.91 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

On the new server, there is no user with ID 1002 and no user with the same name. The file is created like this:

```
$ ll -n
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 10001 10001 0 Jan  9 23:56 testfile
```

I wonder why the file is not created with ID 1002 1000, since the `-a` (archive) option includes `-o` (owner), `-g` (group) and `-p` (permissions) and the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) says

> If a user or group has no name on the source system or it has no match
>       on the destination system, then the numeric ID from the source system is used instead.

Even if I manually add the `--numeric-ids` switch (which I actually don't want), the result is just

```
$ ll -n
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 10001 1000 0 Jan  9 23:56 testfile
```

so it has only kept the GID, not the UID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` must run with `root` privileges on the destination machine.

Option 1: enable SSH login for the `root` user and then specify `root@<IP>` to login.

Option 2: use `rsync` with `sudo` as [decribed in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719439/using-rsync-with-sudo-on-the-destination-machine/719440#719440).