# Using rsync with sudo on the destination machine

Tags: permissions, rsync

Having a [problem that rsync does not set UID and GID as expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719267/rsync-not-setting-the-correct-uid-and-gid-on-destination-files), my gut feeling is that `rsync` should be run as `root` on the destination machine.

I can't login as `root` via SSH, since that's disabled for security purposes. The user on the destination machine is able to use `sudo`.

Is it possible to use `rsync` with `sudo`?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

On the destination machine

1. Find out the path to `rsync`: `which rsync`
2. Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file: `sudo visudo` (see also: [must I use visudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625821/must-use-visudo))
3. Add the line `<username> ALL=NOPASSWD:<path to rsync>`, where *username* is the login name of the user that rsync will use to log on. That user must be able to use `sudo`

Then, on the source machine, specify that `sudo rsync` shall be used:

```
rsync ... --rsync-path="sudo rsync" ...
```

Using it without the `NOPASSWD` on the destination machine will result in the message

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: What is the modification to this that would allow any user in a specific group to do this? Instead of <username> is there a <groupname> version?

Comment: Thanks, only I use pki so I used `-e="ssh -i $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH" --rsync-path="sudo rsync"`

Comment: Of course <username> can now read/write everything as root using rsync, locally and remote, so the part about not being able to log in as root due to security concerns is kinda moot... cause essentially you're doing that now.

Comment: @hmn: not exactly. Disabling root access on SSH basis will prevent some brute force login attacks. In my case, I log on with a keyfile and I need a different password for that than for the sudo command. sudo does quite a good job protecting us, e.g. you cannot have an open root shell forever and it gives you logging. I personally like it.

Comment: Still getting the "not tty present..." error after following these instructions? I was.  Making sure the line I added to `/etc/sudoers` comes at the end of the file (or after any group rules which may affect the same user) solved the problem for me.

Comment: I'm using this solution but would like to improve security by restricting the args the user can pass to rsync on the destination server. Typically I would limit the args that can be used with `<username> ALL=NOPASSWD:<path to rsync> <args>` but I don't know what the args would be when called remotely like this. Any ideas?

Comment: @PeteCornell: I'm not aware of a solution that limits the arguments. However, I have seen a solution to just allow a single command exactly as configured once before. You could have multiple of these. Unfortunately, I don't have a link for that at hand

Comment: OK thanks, I think I will have to move to a push architecture to avoid the unconfined sudo rsync situation.

Comment: [Here is another option](https://serverfault.com/a/858819/77156) for bypassing potential `Defaults requiretty` SSHD configuration on the remote side.

Comment: Useful shell alias: `alias rsync-sudo='rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'`

Comment: So useful thank you so much!!

Comment: Note that the added configuration should go _after_ any other configurations that apply to your user (such as group membership), as apparently the sudoers file is last-configuration-wins!

Comment: Keep in mind that order matters in `sudoers`. I set `<username> ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync` in `/etc/sudoers.d/username` and expected that is would do the job. Turned out in my `/etc/sudoers` there was a `%some-usergroup        ALL=(ALL)       ALL` line (username is a member of that some-usergroup) after `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d`. Moving the `%some-usergroup <..>` line before `@includedir` fixed my remote `sudo rsync` problems.

Answer (score 18):

My solution is to use `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`, if it ask for password you can use workaround like this:

```
rsync -avz --stats --rsync-path="echo <SUDOPASS> | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync"  user@192.168.1.2:/ .
```

However, it is better to not type your password on the commandline, where it sill be stored in terminal history. Instead, you can use `read -s` to prompt for the password without showing it:

```
read -s -p "Remote sudo password: " SUDOPASS && rsync -avz --stats --rsync-path="echo $SUDOPASS | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync"  user@192.168.1.2:/ .
```

(Note: `-p` to prompt isn't supported in all shells (e.g. zsh), if you get an error you can leave it off, or echo before reading instead)

Comment: This works great to pull between ec2 instances (minus the echo <SUDOPASS> part). Dont forget to add a Security Group rule to allow port 22 from the sgID itself, to the instances that need it. 

`rsync -aPvhe ssh -A --rsync-path="sudo -Sv && sudo rsync" ec2-user@<privateEC2-IP>:/home/ec2-user/testfile /home/ec2-user`
Note, the testfile was 700 root:root and this copied the file while maintaining permissions.

Comment: Did not work for me. I am getting the error 

`[sudo] password for sysadmin: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required`

Comment: I faced @JoyceBabu 's error message. Upon scribbling there seems to be a flaw with the use of `read` here. `read` is run before `rsync` to define a _local variable_. Yet when `--rsync-path` injects `echo`'s stdout to `sudo -Sv` it is calling a _remote variable_. One could use correct order of quotes (`'` `"`) to expand local variable within remote command, yet then the issue of logs and history picking up plain-text password is back on menu. I tried injecting `read` before `echo`, but that leaves me with a blank page (not input), and a need to `CTRL-C`. _NOPASSWD_ works for non-X environment.

Answer (score 9):

You can have the remote sudo ask you for your password through X-windows. Here's a way to do that:

1. Make sure `ssh-askpass` is installed on the remote host (and that you are using X-windows, of course)
2. Make sure this is in `/etc/sudo.conf`:

```
# Path to askpass helper program
Path askpass /usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

3. Add these options to rsync: `-e "ssh -X" --rsync-path="sudo -A rsync"`

   - `ssh -X` will forward your X-windows information and port to your
     remote session
   - `sudo -A` will make sudo use ssh-askpass to ask you for your password

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18; create /etc/sudo.conf (if it does not already exist) on the destination m/c

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 as well

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137992/20230 and https://superuser.com/a/1230011/137881

Answer (score 4):

The solutions which suggest modifying `/etc/sudoers` or `echo`ing the password into a pipe didn't feel comfortable.

Instead, I've found success with the answer posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/300910/317127). My slight modification prepends a `sudo` to the rsync call in the second line in order to have unrestricted write permissions on the local machine as well.

```
stty -echo; ssh myUser@REMOTE_SERVER "sudo -v"; stty echo  
sudo rsync -avze ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync' myUser@REMOTE_SERVER:/REMOTE_PATH/ /LOCAL_PATH/
```

Comment: sudo on rsync is very inelegant..   Surely you'd be better off using a specific user which has permissions on the remove side via facl on the specific directories you want to read or modify.

Comment: Actually I find this one the most elegant solution for simple one-off jobs, as it **requires no modifications on remote systems**. One would need to replace first line with `ssh -t myUser@REMOTE_SERVER "sudo -v"` instead for most systems, though. For recurring (esp. automated) jobs, other solutions are preferred as noted (including `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `sshd_config` and creating key for root access, allowing that key to only run rsync in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`; perhaps even paired with Apparmor/SElinux read-only restrictions for it if one cares extra about security etc)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no access to sudoers file,
just create a wrapper script for the ssh command.

ssh_sudo:

```
{ 
  echo $PASSWORD;
  cat - ;
} | ssh $* &
```

At first, this passes the password to the ssh client's sudo process in order to start rsync on the remote side. Next all input coming from the local rsync is piped to ssh.

Finally call rsync e.g. with:

```
PASSWORD=<SUDOPASS> rsync -avzue ssh_sudo --rsync-path "sudo -S rsync" SRC DST
```

I guess the security aspect here is not that bad, you'll only have to save the password locally as env var. Reading it from a file should work as well...

Comment: `PASSWORD=<SUDOPASS> rsync...` logs the password into your shell's history, at least for bash

Answer (score 1):

When trying to solve this same problem in the `ansible` `synchronize` module, I came across this question and would like to draw some attention to the solution https://askubuntu.com/a/1263657/874618 by Simon Schmid. Can't upvote or comment using my account (not enough reputation points), so I'll post this as another answer:

Simon's solution not only is the safest alternative in that it requires no changes to `sudoers` and passes the password using the environment (so that it will not pop up in history files and logs), it also works without changes to the **target** machine, which is very convenient if you want to `rsync` to lots of fresh machines and do not want to reconfigure them just for this command.

After playing around with it a bit, I've managed to inline the shell commands used for wrapping `ssh` on the **host** machine as well, so it is possible to just use a single `rsync` line:

```
PASSWORD=<SUDOPASS> rsync -avzue '/bin/sh -c "{ echo $PASSWORD; cat - ; } | ssh $0 $* &"' --rsync-path "sudo -S rsync" SRC DST
```

Happy syncing ;-)

Comment: `PASSWORD=<SUDOPASS> rsync...` logs the password into your shell's history, at least for bash

Comment: This is true. However, as described, I use this solution within an automation tool (ansible) that does not log anything entered. There is a very small chance that someone can observe your environment variables from another process, but it sounds like a security misconfiguration anyway if that is possible.