# rsync with remote sudo fails over ssh on Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2

Tags: rsync

rsync with remote sudo fails over ssh on Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2

rsync version 3.1.2 protocol version 31 - same on local and remote

OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017 - same on local and remote

I have checked for spurious output from .bashrc using

`$ ssh user@host /bin/true > out.dat`

which results in

`$ ls -l *.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 May 22 23:33 out.dat`

-- The [redacted] command is

`rsync -AEavvvogt --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --debug=CONNECT -e "ssh -i /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa -tt -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --exclude-from=/home/xxx/backup.exclude --delete --link-dest=../$lastdt /etc $dest/$dt`

-- The [redacted] output is

```
opening connection using: ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -tt -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l user xxx "sudo rsync" --server -vvvlogDtpAre.iLsfxC --delete --link-dest ../20190506_021137 . /home/backups/xxx/20190522_232738 (20 args)

OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to xxx [192.168.1.120] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0

debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3

debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000

debug1: Authenticating to xxx:22 as 'user'

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256

debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

debug1: kex: server->client cipher: <email address hidden> MAC: <implicit> compression: none

debug1: kex: client->server cipher: <email address hidden> MAC: <implicit> compression: none

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

debug1: Server host key: xxx

Warning: Permanently added 'xxx,192.168.1.120' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:xxx /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

debug1: Server accepts key: xxx

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

Authenticated to xxx ([192.168.1.120]:22).

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]

debug1: Requesting <email address hidden>

debug1: Entering interactive session.

debug1: pledge: network

debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype <email address hidden> want_reply 0

debug1: tty_make_modes: no fd or tio

debug1: Sending environment.

debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8

debug1: Sending command: sudo rsync --server -vvvlogDtpAre.iLsfxC --delete --link-dest ../20190506_021137 . /home/backups/xxx/20190522_232738

protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?

(see the rsync man page for an explanation)

rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.2]

[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=2, file=compat.c, line=178): about to call exit(2)
```

/etc/sudoers contains

```
user ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

...which I have tried placing above (as is the default) and below lines beginning %admin and %sudo
and the space in "ALL= NOPASSWD..." doesn't seem to make any difference

I followed the instructions at

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh

[Using rsync with sudo on the destination machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719439/using-rsync-with-sudo-on-the-destination-machine)

...which worked on 16.04, so I wonder if there may be a bug, although grateful for any other suggestions, as I am unsure how to debug/investigate further.

Comment: Is there anything in your remote shell's startup files that writes to standard output? see [Rsync seems incompatible with .bashrc (causes “is your shell clean?”)](https://serverfault.com/a/805532)

Comment: @steeldriver `$ ssh user@host /bin/true > out.dat` gives
`$ ls -l *.dat -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 May 22 23:33 out.dat`
which would suggest not... .bashrc on remote also begins with

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by `-tt` in the ssh options, which I picked up from somewhere as a potential solution to a different error.

Having corrected a remote path error in my script, it works as expected when `-tt` is removed from the ssh options.

Comment: ...on which https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1019923 may be instructive