# Using rsync with sudo

Tags: sudo, rsync

I want rsync with sudo.

1 I try solution from this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155897/1087530):

```
huser@linux:~$ rsync -avz --stats --rsync-path="echo 4321 | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync" /home/huser/mylibs/ ruser@192.168.0.100:/home/ruser  
ruser@192.168.0.100's password:
```

I am confused - rsync shouldn't ask for a password, should it? Ok, I type ruser's password and get error:

```
[sudo] password for ruser: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

Where
ruser is my username in remote Ubuntu 22,
huser is my username in host Ubuntu 22,
4321 is ruser's password (for me ok to keep it in history),
192.168.0.100 is remote machine IP.

2 I try another way, I have ssh key:

```
rsync --rsync-path="sudo -S rsync" -rvz -e "ssh -i /home/huser/key/my_ssh_key" --progress /home/huser/bin/ ruser@192.168.0.100:/home/ruser/
[sudo] password for ruser: 4321
```

And I wait a while for a folder of several bytes to transfer... but nothing happens, not even an error.

3 Let's check that rsync can work without sudo:

```
rsync -avz --stats /home/huser/mylibs/ ruser@192.168.0.100:/home/ruser
```

This works ok.

How I can work with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo -v` option doesn't seem to be working for some reason, perhaps because it's SSH, or because you disabled timeouts. Let's avoid it:

```bash
rsync -avz --stats --rsync-path="{ echo 4321; cat; } | sudo -S rsync" /home/huser/mylibs/ ruser@192.168.0.100:/home/ruser
```

You should see `[sudo] password for ruser:` appear for a second, then it will become `[sudo] password for ruser: sending incremental file list`. The `sudo` may result in the files ending up owned by root. If that's not desired, you should either `chown` them or remove the `sudo`.

Comment: Your script ask `ruser@192.168.0.100's password:` Then I in password 1234 then I see `[sudo] password for ruser: sending incremental file list
./
testfile.txt` And script doesn't finish, I should manually stop it using Ctrl+C. I am confused why rsync again ask password that I already have wrote to script? And how finish automatically?

Comment: "ruser@192.168.0.100's password" is SSH asking you for the password, not rsync. I never see that message because I use SSH keys. I will debug what could be the reason the script doesn't finish later

Comment: I also try with ssh key `rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 22 -i \"/home/huser/key path with space/my_ssh_key\"" --stats --rsync-path="{ echo 4321; cat; } | sudo -S rsync" /home/huser/mylibs/ ruser@192.168.0.100:/home/ruser` Now don't ask password. But how  remove my password from script in case of key? And script doesn't finish automatically again... Thank you